# Capable of building Mesa 20.1 but unable to install

Tags: opengles

I have successfully built Mesa 20.1 on Raspberry Pi OS 64bit, using burtoogle's patch (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=276207#p1681901)

I followed the instructions from mesa3d.org:

```
meson builddir/
ninja -C builddir/
sudo ninja -C builddir/ install
```

The problem is that the new version of Mesa is not really installed. When doing a "glxinfo | grep Mesa", I get:

```
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 19.3.2
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 19.3.2
```

EDIT - Here is the install log:

```
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1.1.0
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri/libgallium_dri.so
/usr/local/include/KHR/khrplatform.h
/usr/local/include/GLES/egl.h
/usr/local/include/GLES/gl.h
/usr/local/include/GLES/glext.h
/usr/local/include/GLES/glplatform.h
/usr/local/include/GLES2/gl2.h
/usr/local/include/GLES2/gl2ext.h
/usr/local/include/GLES2/gl2platform.h
/usr/local/include/GLES3/gl3.h
/usr/local/include/GLES3/gl31.h
/usr/local/include/GLES3/gl32.h
/usr/local/include/GLES3/gl3ext.h
/usr/local/include/GLES3/gl3platform.h
/usr/local/include/GL/gl.h
/usr/local/include/GL/glcorearb.h
/usr/local/include/GL/glext.h
/usr/local/include/GL/glx.h
/usr/local/include/GL/glxext.h
/usr/local/include/EGL/egl.h
/usr/local/include/EGL/eglext.h
/usr/local/include/EGL/eglplatform.h
/usr/local/include/EGL/eglmesaext.h
/usr/local/include/EGL/eglextchromium.h
/usr/local/include/GL/internal/dri_interface.h
/usr/local/include/gbm.h
/usr/local/share/drirc.d/00-mesa-defaults.conf
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glesv1_cm.pc
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glesv2.pc
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/dri.pc
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gbm.pc
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/egl.pc
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gl.pc
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/local/share/drirc.d
/usr/local/include/GL/internal
/usr/local/include/EGL
/usr/local/include/GL
/usr/local/include/GLES3
/usr/local/include/GLES2
/usr/local/include/GLES
/usr/local/include/KHR
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
```

It's not clear to me where the built material should be placed in order to be effective. Maybe in "/usr" instead of "/usr/local"?

Comment: *"It's not clear to me where the built libs should be placed"* -> Do you know where they have been placed by the install?

Comment: @goldilocks No, I don't know where they have been placed. I guess I can reinstall in order to check that (TBD)

Comment: @goldilocks I included the install log in the question

Answer (score 1):

The libs are all in subdirectories of `/usr/local/lib` (as opposed to `/usr/local/lib` itself), which means they might not be indexed by the system linker.

Try:

```
sudo ldconfig 
ldconfig -p | grep /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/
```

If that shows a bunch of those libs, try starting it up again (the `sudo ldconfig` call might have fixed it).

If not:

```
sudo sh -c echo /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/000-AAA-Mesa.conf
```

The `000-AAA` bit is important because those are processed with alphabetical precedence. Try the `sudo ldconfig` bit again; this time `ldconfig -p` should show the files now.  Can't promise that will make it all work though.

Comment: Thank you @goldilocks. I can't mark your answer as accepted solution because I can't test it anymore (before I saw your answer I made a script that copies all the material from /usr/local into /usr and it seems to work...)

Answer (score 1):

Library paths in `/etc/ld.so.conf` take precedence over whatever you define in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*`. You have 3 options here:

- edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` to put `/usr/local/lib/*` ahead of `/usr/lib/*` and re-run `sudo ldconfig`
- start `glxgears` with the right libs using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ glxgears`. You'll have to set the environment for every program you want to run with new libs.
- install new libs in `/usr/lib` instead of `/usr/local/lib`, overwriting your system libs. Not recommended as this will confuse the package manager.